# Appending td with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, userscripts

So I'm trying to modify this... (this is only part of the code, its too big)

```
<div class="quick_keys">
<!-- end: header -->
<form method="post" action="myawards.php">
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" class="tborder">
<tr>
<td class="thead" colspan="3"><strong>My Awards</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tcat" width="18%"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td class="tcat"><strong>Description</strong></td>
<td class="tcat" width="10%" align="center"><strong>Award</strong></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="trow1"><strong><a href="myawards.php?awid=1">Diamond</a></strong></td>
    <td class="trow1">A valued member of our community.</td>
    <td class="trow1" align="center"><img src="/uploads/awards/3.jpg" alt="Diamond" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td class="trow2"><strong><a href="myawards.php?awid=2">White Hat Helper</a></strong></td>
    <td class="trow2">One that has done well helping others.</td>
    <td class="trow2" align="center"><img src="/uploads/awards/1.jpg" alt="White Hat Helper" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td class="trow1"><strong><a href="myawards.php?awid=3">Speaker of the House</a></strong></td>
    <td class="trow1">This award goes to members that have a lot to say.</td>
    <td class="trow1" align="center"><img src="/uploads/awards/4.jpg" alt="Speaker of the House" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td class="trow2"><strong><a href="myawards.php?awid=4">Member of the Month</a></strong></td>
    <td class="trow2">This is a monthly award for the best member.</td>
    <td class="trow2" align="center"><img src="/uploads/awards/7.jpg" alt="Member of the Month" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
```

Basically what i' m trying to add another row, something like

```
<td class="trow1"><strong><a href="myawards.php?awid=5">Award5</a></strong></td>
<td class="trow1">Description for award here</td>
<td class="trow1" align="center"><img src="/uploads/awards/5.jpg" alt="Award5" /></td>
```

Can anybody tell me how to do this properly? I've been trying to use .append() with jQuery but i've been having trouble figuring it out. I'm sure the solution is a lot more simple than I think... All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Basically what i' m trying to add another ***row***

Note the emphasis I've added to the above: You're trying to add a *row*, so you need a `tr`, not just a bunch of `td`s:

```
$('.tborder').append(
    '<tr>' +   // <== Note
    '<td class="trow1"><strong><a href="myawards.php?awid=5">Award5</a></strong></td>' +
    '<td class="trow1">Description for award here</td>' +
    '<td class="trow1" align="center"><img src="/uploads/awards/5.jpg" alt="Award5" /></td>' +
    '</tr>'    // <== Note
);
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$('.tborder').append(
  '<tr>' + // <== Note
  '<td class="trow1"><strong><a href="myawards.php?awid=5">Award5</a></strong></td>' +
  '<td class="trow1">Description for award here</td>' +
  '<td class="trow1" align="center"><img src="/uploads/awards/5.jpg" alt="Award5" /></td>' +
  '</tr>' // <== Note
);
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" class="tborder">
  <tr>
    <td class="thead" colspan="3"><strong>My Awards</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, worked perfectly! Also, as a question, is there any way to actually make that source code show up on the source code page? I'm basically trying to create a custom userscript, which can select different awards by $("td[class*='trow'] img"), and it fades them and appends them to an array. When I do this for the newly added rewards, however, nothing happens because the new rewards aren't actually being added to the source from client side

Comment: @ArmanShah: You've asked if it's possible to make that show up "in the source code," but that's almost certainly not what you want (and the answer is "no, it isn't, without modifying the source file"). Once you've appended elements, you can select them with `$()`. They do not show up in "view source," but they do show up in the Elements pane of the dev tools.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var tr;
$('#add').click(function(){
 tr = $('<tr/>');
 tr.append("<td class='trow1'><strong><a href='myawards.php?awid=5'>Award5</a></strong></td>");
tr.append("<td class='trow1'>Description for award here</td>");
tr.append("<td class='trow1' align='center'><img src='/uploads/awards/5.jpg' alt='Award5' /></td>");
$('#tableid').append(tr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" class="tborder" id='tableid'>
<tr>
<td class="thead" colspan="3"><strong>My Awards</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tcat" width="18%"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td class="tcat"><strong>Description</strong></td>
<td class="tcat" width="10%" align="center"><strong>Award</strong></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="trow1"><strong><a href="myawards.php?awid=1">Diamond</a></strong></td>
    <td class="trow1">A valued member of our community.</td>
    <td class="trow1" align="center"><img src="/uploads/awards/3.jpg" alt="Diamond" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td class="trow2"><strong><a href="myawards.php?awid=2">White Hat Helper</a></strong></td>
    <td class="trow2">One that has done well helping others.</td>
    <td class="trow2" align="center"><img src="/uploads/awards/1.jpg" alt="White Hat Helper" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td class="trow1"><strong><a href="myawards.php?awid=3">Speaker of the House</a></strong></td>
    <td class="trow1">This award goes to members that have a lot to say.</td>
    <td class="trow1" align="center"><img src="/uploads/awards/4.jpg" alt="Speaker of the House" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td class="trow2"><strong><a href="myawards.php?awid=4">Member of the Month</a></strong></td>
    <td class="trow2">This is a monthly award for the best member.</td>
    <td class="trow2" align="center"><img src="/uploads/awards/7.jpg" alt="Member of the Month" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
    </table>
    
    <input type='button' value='Add Row' id='add'>
```

You can do it like this. On click event of button append the td on tr that you append on table

Comment: Where is the genius down voting every answer. Why don't you post your answer since you are just down voting and running! Tell us what is wrong... don't just down vote and run!

Comment: @Gacci i think they should leave a comment before downvoting.this is not  right.

Answer (score -1):

Here it is a little sample.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('sample');

var row = table.insertRow();

var columns = table.rows[0].cells.length || 3;

for(var i = 0; i < columns; ++i){
    var cell = row.insertCell(i);
    cell.innerHTML = "Cell #"+i;
}
```

```html
<table id='sample'>
    <tr><td>Cell #0</td><td>Cell #1</td><td>Cell #2</td></tr>
 </table>
```